# Embedded Markdown tags in answers have smaller text and are not aligned properly

Tags: bug, tags, design, markdown, responsive-design

Is it possible to reposition and increase the size of Markdown tags embedded in answers?

Over at *[Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour)*, although a question may be tagged with a specific jurisdiction:

> we expect and encourage answers dealing with other jurisdictions ... If you do this, please tag your answer using the tag markdown: [tag: some-tag]. [Source](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

As can be seen in [this answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/74669/jurisdiction-of-file-a-complaint-of-a-party-who-fraudulantly-denies-the-contract/74672#74672) when viewed in "full site" mode on my Android<sup>1</sup> phone:

- The tag's text is somewhat smaller than the rest, making it difficult (for some) to read, although it has also been emboldened with ** **.
- As it sits below the [baseline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography)), it's out of kilter and looks unnatural.

[image]

**Are these changes realistically achievable?**

(<sup>1</sup> Android v.11 [Galaxy Xcover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Xcover) Pro)

Comment: Apologies on behalf of my Android phone for the lack of freehand red circles and the size of the image.

Comment: On desktop it is [a bit better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MztR.png) but still the text is small and harder to read compared to the rest of the sentence.

Comment: For me it doesn't look this bad. The tag box is lower then the baseline, but the font size doesn't differ that much.  [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scSTx.jpg) It does look strange on the mobile site though.